# Compiling Facelets to Java code

Tags: jsf, compilation, facelets

I saw that Jetty and Jasper have JSP compilers that support JSF in JSP.
However, I am interested in compiling Facelets as well. Are there any tools available that would compile it to Java code or bytecode?

Answer (score 8):

Facelets doesn't work that way. Unlike a JSP file, a Facelets file isn't compiled to a Java class. It's instead "compiled" to a XML tree, usually by a SAX parser (which is one of the fastest ways of parsing XML). The XML tree is in turn internally cached in server's memory by [`DefaultFaceletCache`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.7/com/sun/faces/facelets/impl/DefaultFaceletCache.java/) (in case of Mojarra) which can be customized by providing a custom [`FaceletCache`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletCache.html).